# java references new glitch

Tags: java, reference

Have this field

```
Queue<Process> processQueue;
```

Which is set by this method:

```
public void loadProcesses(ProcessGenerator pg, int numberOfProcesses){

        this.numberOfProcesses = numberOfProcesses;
        Process[]array = pg.generateProcesses(numberOfProcesses);
        processQueue = new LinkedList<Process>();

        for(Process x: array){
            processQueue.add((Process)x);
        }

    }
```

However even if creating (i think that i do so) new reference to not change this field:

```
Queue<Process> procQueue = new LinkedList<Process>(processQueue);
```

In some method it is changing `processQueue`. Where is the glitch?

Comment: Did not get it. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: i generate random processes, wchich are modified by methods, but dont want to change the origin queue. So when launching test, only first method work properly but for others I  get zero at one of Process field, because previous method is changing fields which it shouldn't happened.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: You can elaborate your comment a bit and post it as answer.

Comment: Or better, always create new Processes.  You probably shouldn't be trying to reuse an Object anyway.

Comment: yeah but Processes are random and i need to compare three different algorithms with same input data. Thanks for help :)

Comment: `new LinkedList<Process>(processQueue);` will create a new list pointing to the _exact same elements_ as `processQueue`. So if you change those elements you'll see the change in both lists. If you want to have new processes you'll need to iterate over `processQueue`, copy the element and add it to the new list (could be done with a stream in Java 8).

Comment: `i need to compare three different algorithms with same input data.` - in that case there might be a design issue. If the random part is the input data then you could create it only once but make it an immutable object (don't change it) and pass it to the three algorithms. Internally you'd create copies of the data as needed (and _if_ really needed).